# Class similar to javax.microedition.media.control.MIDIControl in Android API?

Tags: android, midi, synthesizer, midi-instrument

Does the Android API have a class similar to `javax.microedition.media.control.MIDIControl`?  I want to generate midi sounds as drums, notes and chords.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly what you are looking for, you can probably put together a solution with [libpd on Android](http://gitorious.org/pdlib).

Answer (score 0):

[android-midi-lib](http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/)

Straight-up Java MIDI implementation usable with Android. You'll have to handle actually playing the samples though, the library will just trigger the events.